# Notifications when an ObservedObject is changed

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, observableobject, observedobject

I have a graphical user interface made of several SwiftUI components (lets call them subviews).
These subviews communicate with each other with the help of ObservableObject / ObservedObject.
When changes are made to one view, the other view is automatically notified and updates itself.

However, one of the subviews is not a SwiftUI view but a SpriteKit SKScene.
Here, too, I would like to react to the changes in an observed value.
But I do not have a view that updates automatically. I want to make adjustments to the sprites, depending on the observed value.

How can I be notified of changes in the value?
Can I call a method as soon as the value of the ObservedObject changes?

Comment: Have you made attempts to make a SKView available in SwiftUI, like in this basic tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit. Then, it's not clear what kind of object you want to render in a SKView other than the SKScene.

Answer (score 10):

It is easy to observe changes in ObservedObject from UIKit or SKScene. The example below is from UIViewController, change this for the equivalent to SKScene:

```
import Combine

class Object: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var value: Int = 10
    @Published var anotherValue: String = "Hello"
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController { 

    let observedObject = Object()
    var cancellableBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // REACT TO ANY @PUBLISHED VARIABLE
        observedObject.objectWillChange.sink { 
              // Do what you want here
        }.store(in: &cancellableBag)

        // REACT ONLY TO ONE SPECIFIED @PUBLISHED VARIABLE
        observedObject.$value.sink { value in
              // Do what you want here
        }.store(in: &cancellableBag)
    }
}
```

Note that `@Published` is a `propertyWrapper` with `projectedValue`. The `projectedValue` in this case is the `Publisher`, that emits events every time the `wrappedValue` will be changed, so in order to access to the `projectedValue` it is necessary to call `$value` instead of `value`.

Comment: Also note, that this publisher is emitted **prior** to the value being changed (ie. objectWillChange). If you attempt to access the value of the property through the ObservableObject it will still have old value.

Comment: @lipka When you observe the ObservableObject's 'objectWillChange' yes, you have the old state and you cannot capture the new value because you get a Void () function when you attemp to get it from the closure. But, in the second case, when you observe a concrete value you get that future value inside the closure.